# Classic ASP Request.QueryString or request.QueryString?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I know that this may be a silly question but I'm new to classic ASP and we have a problem with an application developed in ASP, and I just want to be sure that THERE IS NO difference when writing **Request.QueryString** vs **request.QueryString**, I mean, capital letters should not affect the variables obtained... right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Correct. VBScript is not case-sensitive.

Comment: ...assuming your ASP is written in VBScript (EDIT never mind - there's a tag for that...)

Answer (score 0):

Developing Classic ASP websites for 18 years, and still maintaining a lot of professionnal production applications, I can assure you that the VBScript language used inside Classic ASP scripts is NOT case-sensitive. You can use either of **Request.QueryString** or **request.QueryString**, or even **ReqUEST.QueRysTRInG** !

SIDE-NOTE : Parts of your Classic ASP script that are written in JScript ARE case-sensitive, as JScript is an implementation of ECMAScript 3.